# Displaying all the numbers between 200 and 600

Tags: php

I have to display all the numbers between 200 and 600 (both numbers inclusive) that are divisible by 8:

```
for($i=200;$i<=600;$i++)
{
    if($i%8==0)
        echo $i.',';
}
```

It reaches maximum execution time.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`echo`[`implode`](http://php.net/implode)`(",",`[`range`](http://php.net/range/)`(200,600,8) );`

Comment: about as elegant as it can get. bravo.

Comment: +1 Obviously the best answer. I would delete mine but I can't while it is accepted.

Comment: If one more person upvotes your answer, I get a Populist badge, which would be awesome :D

Comment: Epic win.  Had no idea such a function existed in PHP.  Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Have a gold bade on me then.

Answer (score 12):

1. Why do you test each number?

   Rather than `$i++` you can use `$i += 8`. Then the test becomes redundant.
2. Your output is terminated by `,`

   ```
   ...584,592,500,
                 ^^^^  Extra trailing comma.
   ```

I would do:

```
printf('%d', 200);
for($i = 208; $i <= 600; $i += 8)
{
    printf(', %d', $i);
}
printf('\n');
```